# Is using Kurento Media Server can provide me webcam broadcasting like Red5?

Tags: red5, live-streaming, kurento, broadcasting

I am building a web-based project which has webcam one-way broadcasting part .(A user can open its own cam and some viewers can join its room to only view and listen).
So i have decided to use Kurento Media Server(KMS) because of not having any experince with flash.

**My questions in my head:**

- Do i need anything extra beside KMS to make a user broadcast webcam?
- Can Kurento provide me the live streaming to webpage?
- And What is the difference using Red5 or Kurento?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do i need anything extra beside KMS to make a user broadcast webcam?

You'll probably need a TURN server for users that have some port limitations

> Can Kurento provide me the live streaming to webpage?

Sure! Check the [tutorials](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials.htm) and the [documentation](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introducing_kurento.html) for a full list of features.

> And What is the difference using Red5 or Kurento?

Kurento is more than just a media server. It is a pluggable platform that offers computer vision and augmented reality capabilities, on top of video and audio streaming, recording and playing. It also offers WebRTC out of the box, which is something Red5 can't do as of today.

Disclaimer: I'm part of the Kurento team.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , helped me to shape my thoughts

Comment: hi igracia, could you give a suggestion for a server or server type to deploy broadcasting application ?First time i build broadcasting app,so just want to be sure. I want it to deploy to server and then add kurento support in it.Thanks

Comment: @minchevz We've used AWS quite extensively. Give it a go!